# Automating Query for each month

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, date

I have a query below:

```
select a.ID, 
       a.Date_Reported, 
       b.Date_Received
from tx_ext a 
join tx b on b.id = a.id
AND b.Date_Reported >= convert( datetime, '2018-05-01' ) 
AND b.Date_Reported <= convert( datetime, '2018-05-31' )
```

As you can see, I am currently manually setting the date for May (last month). How can I alter my query, that whatever month I am in, I always run the full previous month. So for example this month is June, so I would like to run values from may alone. And next month is July, so I would like to run june.

I want to automate this, so i don't need to manually enter dates every month

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use:

```
select a.ID, 
       a.Date_Reported, 
       b.Date_Received
from tx_ext a 
join tx b on b.id = a.id
AND b.Date_Reported >= DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, GETDATE()), 0) 
AND b.Date_Reported <= EOMONTH(GETDATE());
```

**[DBFiddle Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=ce490b4445fb4f8cf44ee8689f8ae7a9)**

Please note that end date is `30/06/2018 00:00:00` so I assume that you store Date_Reported as DATE(not DATETIME). If you have time part you need to change to:

```
AND b.Date_Reported < DATEADD(d,1,EOMONTH(GETDATE()))
```

## EDIT

```
select a.ID, 
       a.Date_Reported, 
       b.Date_Received
from tx_ext a 
join tx b on b.id = a.id
AND b.Date_Reported>=DATEADD(month,-1,DATEADD(month,DATEDIFF(month,0,GETDATE()),0))
AND b.Date_Reported<DATEADD(d,1,EOMONTH(GETDATE(),-1)) ;
```

Comment: you should notice it can be used in SQL Server 2012+

Comment: @B3S Yes, EOMONTH is available from SQL Server 2012+ but we have year 2018 and extended support for SQL Server 2008 will end soon.

Comment: i wish you were right :) i have daily requests for sqlserver 2003 environments !

Comment: Yes sorry i have DATETIME so will both AND queries change or just the last restriction?

Comment: also is "EOMONTH" a sql query for end of month?

Comment: @Taz Only last condtition, second EOMONTH is function https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/eomonth-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: When i run it, it seems to get me this months figures (ie June). I would like last months- any idea?

Comment: @Taz Sure I posted entire query to avoid confusion

Comment: @lad2025 that is amazing! Thank you so much! :)

Answer (score 1):

Consider this form too (it can be used in older SQL Server versions).

```
select a.ID, 
       a.Date_Reported, 
       b.Date_Received
from tx_ext a 
join tx b on b.id = a.id
AND YEAR(b.Date_Reported) = CASE WHEN MONTH(GETDATE()) = 1
                                 THEN YEAR(GETDATE()) - 1
                                 ELSE YEAR(GETDATE())
                            END
AND MONTH(b.Date_Reported = CASE WHEN MONTH(GETDATE()) = 1
                                 THEN 12
                                 ELSE MONTH(GETDATE()) - 1
                            END
```